# Creating associations with FactoryGirl

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, factory-bot

I have a `User has_many :accounts, through: :roles` and a `User has_many :owned_accounts, through: :ownerships`, I'm using STI where `Ownership < Roles`. I can't write a working factory for the `Ownership` model and the `owned_account` association, and my tests are failing.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :roles
  has_many :accounts, through: :roles
  has_many :ownerships
  has_many :owned_accounts, through: :ownerships
end
class Account < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :roles
  has_many :users, through: :roles
end
class Role < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :users
  belongs_to :accounts
end
class Ownership < Role
end
```

I have working factories for User, Account, and Role; I can't write a factory for Ownership and the owned_accounts association, however:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :user do
    name "Elmer J. Fudd"
  end
  factory :account do
    name "ACME Corporation"
  end
  factory :owned_account do
    name "ACME Corporation"
  end
  factory :role do
    user
    account
  end
  factory :ownership do
    user
    owned_account
  end
end
```

I started with these tests, but I get an uninitialized constant error and all the tests fail:

```
describe Ownership do
  let(:user)    { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
  let(:account) { FactoryGirl.create(:owned_account) }
  before do
    @ownership = user.ownerships.build
    @ownership.account_id = account.id
  end
  subject { @ownership }
  it { should respond_to(:user_id) }
  it { should respond_to(:account_id) }
  it { should respond_to(:type) }
end

1) Ownership 
     Failure/Error: let(:account) { FactoryGirl.create(:owned_account) }
     NameError:
       uninitialized constant OwnedAccount
     # ./spec/models/ownership_spec.rb:17:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
     # ./spec/models/ownership_spec.rb:21:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error message is because you need to specify parent, or it will assume the factory definition is for an ActiveRecord class of that name.

```
factory :owned_account, :parent => :account do
  name "ACME Corporation"
end
```